# Getting JAR list in JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, junit

Is it possible to get a list of the JAR files in a JUnit test?

I want to read the MANIFEST.MF but when I try to get the JARs via ClassLoaders (which works in normal execution) I only get one file `surefirebooter<somenumbers>.jar`

This isn't test specific code but code I want to test in the JUnit test.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system property `java.class.path` contains all classpath elements, JARs and directories. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

It also works while executing code with the maven-surefire-plugin.